# while loop. sum and product of user inputted numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Build a program that will generate the sum and product of 20 input numbers using the while…loop structure.

Conditions:

- user need to input only 20 numbers
- and get the sum and product of all the numbers.

My code right now is this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Case3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] list = new int[20];
        int sum = 0;
        int product = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int number;

        System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
        number = input.nextInt();

        while (x <= list.length) {
             list[x] = number;
             x++;
             System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
             number = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
             sum += list[i];
             product *=list[i];
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of all values are: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The product of all values are: " + product);
      }

}
```

> --------------------Configuration: --------------------
>
> Add number 1: 1
>
> Add number 2: 2
>
> Add number 3: 3
>
> Add number 4: 4
>
> Add number 5: 5
>
> Add number 6: 6
>
> Add number 7: 7
>
> Add number 8: 8
>
> Add number 9: 9
>
> Add number 10: 10
>
> Add number 11: 11
>
> Add number 12: 12
>
> Add number 13: 13
>
> Add number 14: 14
>
> Add number 15: 15
>
> Add number 16: 16
>
> Add number 17: 17
>
> Add number 18: 18
>
> Add number 19: 19
>
> Add number 20: 20
>
> Add number 21: 21
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   20
>       at Case3.main(Case3.java:16)
>
> Process completed.

Comment: You've just discovered what happens when you try to fit 21 numbers in an array of size 20

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
while (x <= list.length) {
```

with

```
while (x < list.length) {
```

This is because the last iteration will fill more than 20 elements in the array.

Also you should initialize `product` to 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 2):

problem is with x++ so modified it now it works..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] list = new int[19];
    int sum = 0;
    int product = 1;
    int x = 0;
    int number;
    System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
    number = input.nextInt();        
    while (x <list.length) {
         list[x] = number;   
         x++;//1,2,3
         System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
         number = input.nextInt();             
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         sum += list[i];
         product *=list[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of all values are: " + sum);
    System.out.println("The product of all values are: " + product);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This two lines before the while loop is not required.

```
System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
number = input.nextInt();
```

While loop has to be,

```
 while (x < list.length) {
     System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
     list[x] = number;
     x++;
     number = input.nextInt();
 }
```

And the product should be initiated to 1 (NOT to 0), when you are dealing with products.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"
x is an int array size if 20 but its indexes go from 0 till 19.
with this stop condition `x <= list.length` x=0 till 20 effectively trying to initialize x[20] which does not exist.so change to 'x < list.length' and also

```
product = 1;
```